# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable and don't know why

Tags: python, typeerror

So I'm new to programming and was doing a code which was to find the smallest value of 10 int(input()). My code it as follows:

```
x, y = 0, 0 

while x < 10:
    n = int(input())
    y += n
    x += 1
print(y)

s = min(y)
print(s)
```

However the problem I am having is for the like s = min(y) it gives me TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: What are you trying to get with the min function? The min() usualy takes a list not a number

Comment: I think you want y to be a `list`, so `y = []` and instead of `+=` you would say `y.append(n)`

Comment: Hi Alex, just so you are aware the forum isn't for learning to program, but programming problems, I think Samwises answer below is the best one. You are treating an individual int like a list/array by using it in a min().

any 'iterable' issues are to do with lists (or the lack thereof).

Maybe do a bunch of tutorials on the language or something to nail down the basics.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an `int` to another `int` gives you a single `int`, not a list of two ints.  `min` expects an iterable (e.g. a `list`) so it'll error if you just give it an `int`.

Do:

```
x, y = 0, []

while x < 10:
    n = int(input())
    y.append(n)
    x += 1
print(y)
```

Now `y` is a `list[int]`, and you can take the `min` of it:

```
s = min(y)
print(s)
```

You can also create `y` more easily with a simple list comprehension and a `range`:

```
y = [int(input()) for _ in range(10)]
print(min(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect min(5) -> 5 then you got the minimum number of one number - python does not do that.

What you can do is get the minimum of a list of numbers, such as min([5,2]) -> 2. And therefore you should at least write

```
s = min([y])
```

where s would actually come up with the value of y.